# How to not include properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, flotr2

I'd like to dynamically include/remove a property at run time.

The problem I have is, using the Flotr2 Jquery library, I'm stuck in that the legend (a property) doesn't appear to be properly supported in IE. Due to time restraints, I've got the OK to do a quick hack.

So, this is a stripped version the code I have, including my attempt

```
Flotr.draw(
    container, myArrayForGraph, {
        if (!IsThisIe()) {
            legend: {
                show: true,
                container: legendContainer
            },
        }

    });
```

As you can see, I want to call 'IsThisIe()' and if it returns false, then add the legend property.

This isn't working, I'm assuming that we can't do this when Javascript expects a property. The message is

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

I know I could create 2 different objects and have something like

```
if (IsThisIe())
{
 Flotr.draw(
        container, myArrayForGraph, {
   ///etc
}
else
{
 Flotr.draw(
        container, myArrayForGraph, {
                legend:
//etc
}
```

But this is duplicating code, each object has many properties.

So, is there a way to not include properties in the manner I've described or am I stuck with having to manage the code in multiple places??

Comment: What do you mean by "This isn't working"? What actually happens? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Don't browser detect- feature detect, detect for the features the browser actually uses.

Comment: @forgivenson It's fairly easy to see... just read the code.

Comment: oops, apparently I read the whole question except for the error. Somehow my I didn't see that. My bad

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, that won't work. The problem is, IE doesn't display some jquery correclty. There is no error through and I don't have time or the experise to fix it. If you open http://jsfiddle.net/ZFBj5/903/ in IE and then another browser, you'll see the bug. This project is a bolt on to a desktop app, so I'm fortunate in only needing to support it *so* well!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var params = {
    // define properties that should be set in both cases
};
if( !IsThisIe()) {
    params.legend = {show:true,container:legendContainer};
}
Flotr.draw(container, myArrayForGraph, params);
```

Then find out why IE doesn't like your code - start with the error console ;)

---

I have found the bug. It's a part of the code Flotr functions. Find where `Flotr.DOM.node` is defined, and replace it with this:

```
node:function(e) {var t = Flotr.DOM.create("div"),n; t.innerHTML = e; n = t.children[0]; return n;}
```

IE doesn't like it if you nuke the `innerHTML` of an element containing other elements that you are referring to. This fix prevents that issue.

Comment: Actually, IE doesn't show any issues in the error console or the script page... But, it doesn't display the legend (http://jsfiddle.net/ZFBj5/903/) try the fiddle in IE, then another browser and you'll see.. .Thank you for this, I didn't realise I can do this..

Comment: Sorry, using the above results with `SyntaxError: invalid object initializer`,... Also, is params a reserved word, I can't find it online/documented

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I have found the bug in Flotr and provided a fix :)

Comment: I have also contacted the developer of Flotr with this bugfix.

Comment: Yes, I contacted them, twice, no response :(  Thank you for taking so much time